# View in the cart the product's regular price plus the custom options selected for each product added

Tags: magento-1.7, cart, custom-options, shopping-cart

is it possible to view inside a column in the cart, the regular price plus the custom options selected for each product added? (the cost should vary depending on the quantity of the product and the options selected)
wich code should I edit?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be looking at the template `app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml`.  Inside here at the relevant point you can use `$_item->getProduct()->getData('price');` to pull the regular price from the product.  To get the cost of custom options just do some simple arithmetic to take this price off the price that is displayed by default.

Comment: with "get price" I get a value which is not the regular price, but some not defined calculation

Comment: The class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` has the method `getPrice()` defined and you are right it returns a calculated price, hence you need to use `getData('price')` as per my answer to bypass this method and get the actual price from the object rather than the price returned by the method.

Comment: I added this: echo $_item->getProduct()->getData('price'); but it returns some calculated price

Comment: This will return the price attribute saved to the product object, it won't be doing any calculation.

Comment: but how do I multiply it for each product quantity in the cart?

Comment: If you look at the template in my answer you will see the quantity is pulled with `$this->getQty()` so multiply by the value returned from this.

Comment: there's still the custom options value i'm missing

Comment: The price with custom options is the price which is displayed by default...

Comment: this is way too complicated for me i'm afraid...

Comment: Ok, better get yourself a developer then

Comment: maybe, do you have the code for the arithmetic that I should do?

Comment: As per my answer 'take this price off the price that is displayed by default'. This will give you the cost of custom options.

Comment: is there some code sample or guide that I can follow?